# Оптимизация CSS

Tags: html, css, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть такая проблема на сайте. У меня по ходу много `CSS` кода.
Я хочу сделать такую оптимизацию.

> 1) Разделить `css` на файлы `mobile`, `desctop`.
>
> 2) Загружать их отдельно при каждом устройстве свое.

Первое вообще не проблема. Но вот сделать второй пункт затрудняюсь.

Это можно сделать на серверной части, Но я хочу знать есть какие то методы что бы это можно было сделать на клиентской части?

Есть такой вариант.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/style-400.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 960px)">
```

Здесь проблема в том что второй `CSS` браузер все ровно загружает. Но не исполняет если параметр `media` не соответствует браузеру.

Есть альтернативные варианты что бы вот к примеру и второй не загружался если браузер не совпадает с критериями?

Comment: А почему просто не подключить библиотеку Mobile detect http://mobiledetect.net/ и в header проводить проверку if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {  }

Comment: @Арсен Вообще то такие библиотеки много? и у яндекса есть нормальный, но заказчик не хочет сделать все это на серверной части.

Comment: По другому никак!! подключение того или иного файла можно реализовать только на серверной части.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверять ширину экрана устройства на `JavaScript` и загружать нужные стили:

```
// Style from Mobile
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1024) {

    // Make a stylesheet link
    var mobileCSS = document.createElement( "link" );
    mobileCSS.rel = "stylesheet";
    mobileCSS.href = "mobile_styles.css";

    // Insert it at the end of the head in a legacy-friendly manner
    document.head.insertBefore( mobileCSS, document.head.childNodes[ document.head.childNodes.length - 1 ].nextSibling );
}

// Style from Desctop
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1024) {

    // Make a stylesheet link
    var desctopCSS = document.createElement( "link" );
    desctopCSS.rel = "stylesheet";
    desctopCSS.href = "desctop_styles.css";

    // Insert it at the end of the head in a legacy-friendly manner
    document.head.insertBefore( desctopCSS, document.head.childNodes[ document.head.childNodes.length - 1 ].nextSibling );
}
```

Comment: Использую как последний вариант, если другого выхода не будет.

Comment: @RazGalstyan если умнее делать, то могу помочь с проверкой мобильных устройств и ОС. Без огромных библиотек.